# AWS Lambda - Swift Operation not permitted

Tags: swift, aws-lambda, permissions

I am trying to compile Swift code via AWS Lambda.
Therefore I am using an Ubuntu 18.04 Image as base.
The Swift Version is 5.0.1.

When the image is executed locally, it works fine.
When I try to execute it in AWS Lambda, I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: /tmp/project/src/a.out: Operation not
> permitted\nclang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use
> -v to see invocation)

I think that the problem is caused by the read-only aws lambda container, that only allows to write into the /tmp/ folder.
Do you know how to fix this error? It seems that swift needs permissions for folders, it doesnt have permission for?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# install clang 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y clang

# install wget 
RUN apt-get install -y wget

# install swift dependencies 
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl3 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev 
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    binutils \
    git \
    libc6-dev \
    libcurl4 \
    libedit2 \
    libgcc-5-dev \
    libpython2.7 \
    libsqlite3-0 \
    libstdc++-5-dev \
    libxml2 \
    pkg-config \
    tzdata \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libbsd-dev 

RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev

# install swift 5.0.1 
RUN wget https://swift.org/builds/swift-5.0.1-release/ubuntu1804/swift-5.0.1-RELEASE/swift-5.0.1-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz RUN tar xzf swift-5.0.1-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz RUN mv swift-5.0.1-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04 /usr/lib/swift RUN echo "export PATH=/usr/lib/swift/usr/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 

RUN . ~/.bashrc

RUN chmod -R o+r /usr/lib/swift
```

**This is the command executed in the AWS-Lambda handler function:**

```
swiftc hello_world.swift -o a.out
```

**hello_world.swift**

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output must be set in **tmp** folder

```
swiftc hello_world.swift -o /tmp/a.out
```

Comment: I tried this, but its still not working :(